# Installing ThinkFan error

Tags: apt, 18.04, thinkpad

Today I was installing ThinkFan with [this tutorial](http://x220.mcdonnelltech.com/ubuntu/), everything went fine until I found out that I can't

```
echo "options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf
```

because of Permission denied. So I used `su` and the command did run. Afer that I found out that I'm completely missing some files including default temperature settings and the service can't start

```
● thinkfan.service - simple and lightweight fan control program
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-21 21:40:53 CEST; 7ms ago
  Process: 3115 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan $DAEMON_ARGS (code=exited, status=4)

srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=4
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: WARNING: Using default temperature inputs in /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal.
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 systemd[1]: thinkfan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal: No such file or directory
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: add_sensor: Error getting temperature.
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal: No such file or directory
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 systemd[1]: Failed to start simple and lightweight fan control program.
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: Error parsing temperatures:
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: readconfig: Error getting temperature.
srp 21 21:40:53 petr-x230 thinkfan[3115]: Refusing to run without usable config file!
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, reinstalling did work:
I used:

> sudo apt install --reinstall thinkfan